Calculus for the practical man chapter 4 problem 20 (The last one!)
A fighter plane is flying in a straight line on a level course to cross the course of a bomber which is also flying on a level course in a straight line. The fighter is at a level 500 ft above the bomber and their courses cross at an angle 60 degrees. Both planes are headed toward the crossing of their courses and on the same side of it, the bomber flying at 200 miles per hour and the fighter at 300. At the moment when the fighter is 10 miles and the bomber 7 miles from the crossing point, how rapidly are they approaching one another in a straight line joining the two planes?
The book's answer is 4.52 mi./min.
My "solution" *Edited
Beginning with the given I labelled the distance from the bomber to the crossing $b$ such that $\frac{db}{dt}=-200$ miles per hour and respectively for the fighter the distance as $a$ and so, $\frac{da}{dt}=-300$ miles per hour. Additionally I defined the third side of the triangle containing 60 degrees as a function of the other sides via the cosine rule, $l=\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2abcos60^o}$ which simplifies to $l=\sqrt{a^2+b^2-ab}$. It's derivative is, $dl=\frac{1}{2}(a^2+b^2-ab)^{-\frac{1}{2}}*(2ada+2bdb-bda-adb)$ or simplified, $\frac{2ada+2bdb-bda-adb}{2\sqrt{a^2+b^2-ab}}$. This seemed logical as the inputs would be the given 7 and 10 miles for a and b as well as their rates known.
Next I focused on the distance between the planes themselves, $s=\sqrt{(\frac{500}{5280})^2+l^2}$ so it's derivative would be, $ds=\frac{1}{2}((\frac{500}{5280})^2+l^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}*2ldl$ or with substitution, $ds=\frac{2ada+2bdb-bda-adb}{2\sqrt{(\frac{500}{5280})^2+a^2+b^2-ab}}$.
Lastly I used the time differential to express the rates and got, $\frac{ds}{dt}=\frac{2a\frac{da}{dt}+2b\frac{db}{dt}-b\frac{da}{dt}-a\frac{db}{dt}}{2\sqrt{(\frac{500}{5280})^2+a^2+b^2-ab}}$. Which given the rates is, $\frac{ds}{dt}=\frac{200b+300a-600a-400b}{2\sqrt{(\frac{500}{5280})^2+a^2+b^2-ab}}$ this gave the answer approximately equal to -4.125 miles per minute. I'm sure I've messed up tremendously here but I would appreciate a worked answer and some points on my illogical thinking, thanks.

Watch out for units. Also, aren’t $da/dt$ and $db/dt$ both negative?

I suppose they would be as they approach the point and the distance decreases

I'm going to calculate with the rates negative and see what I get

the negative rate is 4.3993

FWIW I computed this using vectors (and Mathematica), obtaining a result of 4.41 miles per minute instead. (The 500-ft vertical separation is also not significant: it changes the aforementioned value by less than one part in one thousand. So you can treat this as zero without any meaningful impact, which should make the calculation substantially simpler.)

That said, the big issue here is units: Plugging 500 feet into the same formulas that are using miles per hour is not going to fly. Pick a compatible set of units (e.g., miles for distances and mph for speed) and stick with them at the end. Otherwise you're all but guaranteed to get something nonsensical.

is the rest of the material also nonsensical, because I'm trying to change my approach longer term than this singular problem

converting the units gives me -4.125 miles per minute

I skimmed your posted analysis, which I thought was well written, but I found that it simply took too much effort for me to follow.  So, I will provide my own approach, and then, if you have any questions, you can post a comment-question following my answer.  I will automatically be flagged, and then I will respond.
First of all, I personally have trouble visualizing in $~3~$ dimensions.  So, my initial take on the problem was to temporarily pretend that the two aircraft are at the same altitude, rather than one aircraft being $~500~$ feet above the other.  Given the speeds that the two aircraft are each approaching the crossing point, you would have a triangle with the two paths forming an angle of $~60^\circ~$ with the crossing point.
From this, you can create a distance function based on time.  Let $~d(t)~$ denote the distance at a specific point in time measured in miles, as a function of hours.
Then, you can drop the pretense that the two aircraft are on the same plane.  So, the distance $~d(t)~$ and the distance $~\dfrac{500}{5280}~$ miles form a right triangle, so that the actual distance between the two aircraft is
$$e(t) = \sqrt{ ~[ ~d(t)~]^2 + \left[ ~\frac{500}{5280} ~\right]^2 ~}.$$
Then, $~e(t)~$ represents the actual distance, measured in miles, as a function of time, measured in hours.
Then, you compute $~e'(t),~$ which will represent the rate of change of distance (in miles) as a function of time (in hours).  Then, you evaluate $~e'(t)~$ at the specific point where the two aircraft are 10 miles and 7 miles from the crossing point.
Then, you divide by $~60~$ to express rate of change in miles per minute, and then (presumably) round to $~2~$ decimal places.

Unless otherwise specified, distance is measured in miles, and time is measured in hours.
To compute $~d(t),~$ initially pretend that the two aircraft are on the same altitude.  Further, assume that at time $~t = 0,~$ the fighter, which flies at $~300~$ mph is $~10~$ miles away, and the bomber, which flies at $~200~$ mph, is $~7~$ miles away.
Therefore, at time $~t>0,~$ the distances of the two aircraft from the crossing point are $~(10 - 300t)~$ and $~(200 - 7t).~$
Therefore, since $~2\cos(60^\circ) = 1,$
$$[ ~d(t) ~]^2 = (10 - 300t)^2 + (7 - 200t)^2 - [(10 - 300t) ~(7 - 200t)]. \tag1 $$
Now, dropping the pretense, and accommodating the difference in altitude,
$$[ ~e(t) ~]^2 = [ ~d(t) ~]^2 + \left[ ~\frac{500}{5280} ~\right]^2.$$
Using implicit differentiation, and considering that an intermediate goal is to express $~e'(0)~$ in terms of miles per hour, you have that
$$[ ~2 \times e(t) \times e'(t) ~] = [ ~2 \times d(t) \times d'(t) ~] \implies $$
$$e'(t) = \frac{d(t) \times d'(t)}{e(t)} ~: ~t = 0. \tag2 $$
Then, whatever $~e'(0)~$ computes to, in (2) above, must be scaled by $~\dfrac{1}{60}~$ to convert to miles per minute.

So, in order to complete the problem, you have to compute

$\displaystyle d(0) = \sqrt{10^2 + 7^2 - (10)(7)} = \sqrt{79}.$

$\displaystyle e(0) = \sqrt{ ~79 + \left[ ~\frac{500}{5280} ~\right]^2 ~} \approx 8.89352.$

$d(t) \times d'(t)~$ at $~t = 0.$ 
This is shown below.


Note that (for example) $~\displaystyle \dfrac{d}{dt}\left[ ~(10 - 300t)^2 ~\right] = 2 \times (10 - 300t) \times (-300) ~].$
Evaluating this at $~t = 0 ~$ gives $~2 \times 10 \times -300.$
Therefore, using (1) above, and using implicit differentiation,
$$2 ~d(0) ~d'(0) $$
$$= [ ~2 ~(10) ~(-300) ~] + ~[ ~2 ~(7) ~(-200) ~] - [ ~(10) ~(-200) ~] - [ ~(7) ~(-300) ~] .$$
Therefore,
$$~d(0) ~d'(0) $$
$$= [ ~-3000 ~] + [ ~- 1400 ~] + [ ~1000 ~] + [ ~1050 ~] = - 2350.$$
Therefore, using (2) above, expressing $~e'(0)~$ in terms of miles per hour gives (approximately):
$$\frac{-2350}{8.89352}.$$
Therefore, the final answer is (approximately)
$$\frac{-2350}{8.89352 \times 60} \approx -4.40396 ~\text{miles/minute}.$$
For what it's worth, I am unable to resolve my answer with the official solution of $~4.52~$ miles/minute.
If someone can find a mistake in my analysis, please leave a comment.

Your worked solution seems good off my skimming, I'll look into it with more detail later but off the bat it seems to be the right idea. I think your answer may be slightly off on the account of not including the height of 500 ft which has a minimal impact as commented earlier by semiclassical. Thanks for the help

@Tisamemario If you read my answer more closely, you will see that while $~d(t)~$ ignores the difference in altitude, $~e(t)~$ accommodates the difference in altitude.

Excuse my lack of being prudent, I gave a very superficial look because I had to go. Upon closer inspection I appreciate the work you've put in and found your use of time in the formulas and derivation of e'(t) helpful. I don't see anything inherently wrong with your logic, but of course coming from the inquisitor my word isn't worth very much. Thanks for the help, I'll continue work on this at a later date
